# Spring Integration TCP Grouping by Tokens

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm listening an IP with a specific port and print out the messages. The sample message is like the following:

```
[LOG_PATTERN] ABC1025...
[LOG_PATTERN] (XYZ-COULD-BE-A-MSG
[LOG_PATTERN] -WITH-DASH
[LOG_PATTERN] -SEPARATED-TEXT)
[LOG_PATTERN] ABC1026...
[LOG_PATTERN] (DEF-ANOTHER-SAME-KIND
[LOG_PATTERN] -OF-DASH-SEPARATED-TEXT)
[LOG_PATTERN] ABC1027...
...
```

How could I group each message by specifying a start and end token for example. So that, when it is started with ABC, then it would combine/group the next message until it found the next ABC. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom deserializer; deserializers are described in [the documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#connection-factories).

> TCP is a streaming protocol; this means that some structure has to be provided to data transported over TCP, so the receiver can demarcate the data into discrete messages. Connection factories are configured to use (de)serializers to convert between the message payload and the bits that are sent over TCP. This is accomplished by providing a deserializer and serializer for inbound and outbound messages respectively. A number of standard (de)serializers are provided.
>
> ...

It's generally easier if you can detect the end of a set of messages, based on content (e.g. `)` in your example) rather than detecting the start of a new set. You can't "push" bytes back into a standard input stream after detecting the next `ABC...`.

The upcoming 5.0 release (currently milestone 7 is available) allows customizing the `InputStream` by wrapping it in a `PushbackInputStream` which **does** allow pushing back bytes (only 1 by default, but configurable). See [Advanced Techniques](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M7/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-advanced-techniques)

> ...
>
> The framework provides a single implementation DefatulTcpNetConnectionSupport which creates simple TcpNetConnection objects by default. It has two properties pushbackCapable and pushbackBufferSize; when push back is enabled, the implementation returns a subclass that wraps the connection’s InputStream in a PushbackInputStream. Aligned with the PushbackInputStream default, the buffer size defaults to 1. This enables deserializers to "unread" (push back) bytes into the stream.

With earlier versions, you would have to keep the pre-read bytes in some state somewhere; in which case it might be easier to do the aggregation in a downstream component.